# Message box to confirm data change operation

Tags: vba, excel

I have my submit button code like this:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Overall").Activate
With Me
   If Len(.ComboBox1.Value) * Len(.TextBox1.Value) * Len(.ComboBox2.Value) * Len(.ComboBox3.Value) * Len(.TextBox2.Value) * Len(.TextBox3.Value) * Len(.ComboBox4.Value) * Len(.ComboBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox4.Value) * Len(.TextBox5.Value) * Len(.TextBox6.Value) * Len(.ComboBox6.Value) * Len(.TextBox7.Value) * Len(.TextBox8.Value) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Please Complete All Fields Before Submit"

        Else

            eRow = Sheet9.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            Cells(eRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Text
            Cells(eRow, 2).Value = TextBox2.Text
            Cells(eRow, 3).Value = TextBox3.Text
            Cells(eRow, 4).Value = TextBox1.Text
            Cells(eRow, 5).Value = ComboBox3.Text
            Cells(eRow, 6).Value = TextBox4.Text
            Cells(eRow, 7).Value = TextBox5.Text
            Cells(eRow, 8).Value = ComboBox4.Text
            Cells(eRow, 15).Value = ComboBox6.Text
            Cells(eRow, 10).Value = ComboBox5.Text
            Cells(eRow, 11).Value = TextBox7.Text
            Cells(eRow, 12).Value = TextBox8.Text
            Cells(eRow, 13).Value = TextBox6.Text
            Cells(eRow, 14).Value = ComboBox2.Text

            End If
    End With
    End Sub
```

I wish to add on a confirmation pop out message box to alert user that if the value which is being key in in TextBox8 is exceed 3.0

If user select Yes, then only will store the data inside excel sheet, but if the user select no, another pop out message box will be display to inform user to re-type the value in TextBox8.

Where should I add in the vbYesNo message box?

Comment: Add another `If` block right after the first `Else`. Also you should do something with the `Cells(eRow, #).Value` as Sheet9 may not be always active.

Comment: Take look at here [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: This post of mine has another approach and might be of, at least theoretical, interest: http://yoursumbuddy.com/userform-event-class-validating-controls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something like this before the `Cells` change:

```
If TextBox8.Value > 3 Then
    If MsgBox("TextBox8 > 3" & vbCrLf & "Continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
        MsgBox "Please change the value of TextBox8"
        TextBox8.SetFocus
    Else
        '//eRow = ...
    End If
End If
```

It will display a `YesNo` MsgBox to ask the user to continue. If the user chooses `No` a second MsgBox with the notice will show, and then the TextBox will be activated.